# Ruby on rails : send_file returns a page full of bytes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, file, download, paperclip

I'm simply trying to download a file from a controller (in order to manage authorizations) and the only result I get is a **page full of bytes**. 
I tried to set different configurations in the production.rb and environment.rb (uncomment X-sendfile, etc...), I didn't find another similar issue as well.

If I delete the :path and :url parameter from my send_file method in my MemberFile model, it works fine but obviously files are public and that's not what I want. Authorizations are managed by a controller.

I expect the exact same result as what happens when the file is public...

Thank you for your help !

**member_file.rb**

```
class MemberFile < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :member

  validates :member_id, presence: true

  has_attached_file :uploaded_file,
                    :url => "/member_files/get/:id",
                    :path => "#{Rails.root}/app/assets/test_member_files/:member_id/:id/:basename.:extension"
  validates_attachment :uploaded_file, content_type: { content_type: ["image/jpeg", "image/gif", "image/png", "application/pdf"] }

  Paperclip.interpolates :member_id do |attachment, style|
    attachment.instance.member_id
  end

end
```

**member_file_controller.rb**

```
def show
    @member_file = MemberFile.find(params[:id])
    authorize! :upload_files, @member_file.member
    send_file @member_file.uploaded_file.path, :type => @member_file.uploaded_file_content_type
  end
```

**routes.rb**

```
get 'member_files/get/:id' => 'member_files#show'
```

**Download link**

```
<td><%= link_to f.uploaded_file_file_name, f.uploaded_file.url, action: "download" %></td>
```

(with our without `action: "download"` doesnt change anything)

**result**

[Page full of bytes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iaEcA.png)

**EDIT 1**

When I refresh the latter page, the download is launched ! Any idea ? :/

Comment: Ruby has no `send_file` method, please correct the title.

Comment: Looks like a mimetype is required.

Comment: I corrected the title. In send_file I give the info concerning the mimetype : "image/jpeg", "application/pdf" or whatever... Maybe the browser doesn't see this field or I miss something in the code :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the answer is simple : juste change `get` in `post` in **routes.rb** and add `method: 'post'` to the link...

Answer (score -1):

please use send_data in place of send_file

Comment: I still have the same issue with send_data : 
`@filepath = @member_file.uploaded_file.path
    File.open(@filepath, 'r') do |f|
      send_data f.read, :filename => "myfile.jpeg", :type => @member_file.uploaded_file_content_type, :disposition => "attachment"
    end`